# QR-Code Generator works locally but not on shared hosting

Tags: php, qr-code

I'm a beginner and it's my very first post here so I hope I'm doing this right!

I am using this library in order to generate a QR code in php:
https://github.com/endroid/qr-code

Everything works perfectly locally, but when I upload everything on the remote server (shared hosting), it doesn't work anymore:
http://www.kibo.am/kibo/productbarcodes/FNSKU_label_generator.php

I have isolated the issue to the QR code generator: it works when I deactivate the lines of code that call the library to generate the code.

```
$qrCode = new QrCode($fullsku);
$qrCode->setSize($qrCodeSize);
$qrCode->setMargin(0);
$qrCode->setEncoding('UTF-8');
$qrCodeimg = imagecreatefromstring($qrCode->writeString());
imagecopy($im, $qrCodeimg, $margin, $margin, 0, 0, $qrCodeSize, $qrCodeSize);
imagedestroy($qrCodeimg);
```

You can test the result without those lines of code (and without the QR code):
http://www.kibo.am/kibo/productbarcodes/FNSKU_label_generator.php?qr=false

My guess is that some php modules are not activated on the shared hosting?
www.kibo.am/phpinfo.php

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the logs?

Comment: probably there is a php built-in function that isn't installed on your production server?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to find the error messages. Typically, it'll be sent to an error log. If not, you need to ensure it does.

Comment: Look at the error you're generating. View the actual http traffic, and you'll see this: `<br><b>Fatal error</b>:  Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in <b>/home2/trouni/public_html/kibo/productbarcodes/vendor/endroid/qr-code/src/QrCode.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />`

Comment: Given the error above and the fact that it works locally, I'm going to guess that you're running a different PHP version on your local box compared with the remote server. Get your versions in sync (the higher the better), and then fix the error.

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed a php version discrepancy. I've changed it on the remote server and it now works :) Thanks @Simba